# how to detect if a users keyboard is in AZERTY in Java?

Tags: java, javafx

There is currently a bug in JavaFX (https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30669, free registration required) which makes it so that if you are using an azerty keyboard layout and specify an accelerator with Z in it, on Mac it only fires when typing a W. I need to work around this bug as I need to release my product now.

So I'd like to detect Mac+Azerty and if so change the accelerator to using W. I know how to detect Mac, and I know how to detect the keyboard's locale (using InputContext#getLocale()) but how do I know if the current locale has an azerty keyboard layout? Do I have to check against a hardcoded list of known locales which use an azerty layout? If so, where would I find such a list?

Comment: Does this bug only occur for AZERTY layouts or also for other layouts such as QWERTZ?

Comment: I wouldn't know actually..why?

Comment: Just curious, it's the first layout that came to mind when you mentioned that the Z key was not in the "normal" QWERTY position. QWERTZ keyboards have the Y and Z keys swapped, which is great fun for unsuspecting users who need to make BIOS changes and confirm with Y.

Comment: I think this is caused by the JDK bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022079 / https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8019498 and concerns all non-QWERTY layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't "check against a hardcoded list of known locales" as many people may have a french locale with a keyboard that does not matches the locale, if they bought their computer in the US and use it in quebec with a french interface. I am personally worst, as I'm having a dvorak layout... ;-) And I just want to imagine how many variants of spanish-based layout there may be available...

My best and more portable advice would be to not try to detect something that is hardly detectable, but give some "default" keyboard mappings for (e.g.) qwerty keyboards that would work for most of your userbase, and create a configuration panel that enables your user to change the key mapping for your application by typing the new keys, if they don't like the defaults.

edit:

ah... that can be indeed a different problem... maybe you could anyway make a combobox preference for all non-us keyboard on macosx that has keys with a modifier that get changed?

To answer your question more "straightforwardly", here are a few results I found on google:

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/412482/java/java/Finding-language-setting-locale-keyboard
- http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,23501.

both lead towards [`java.awt.im.InputContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/im/InputContext.html):

```
InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();  
System.out.println(context.getLocale().toString());
```

I never tried this in java, so I can't help you more than with my google-fu, but I really hope this helps :-)

Comment: Agree. Make it a checkbox and explicitly ask the user the first time (with a suitable explanation)

Comment: Hmm while I follow your explanation, my only problem is actually undo (shortcut+z), the bug doesn't manifest itself when typing. So it would be a bit weird to ask the user for a keymapping for undo.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort zmo, but that is exactly where I stranded too :) In my question I also mention using InputContext#getLocale() but my problem is what to do from that point.

Comment: hum... I now get your point, and maybe you got a point about matching against "locales". Though I don't know what the locales it returns look likes, but I'm pretty sure it will give you the country version of the keyboards (`fr_FR` being "azerty", whereas you may get `fr_CA` for french canadian keyboard... which is a french-qwerty – though nobody likes it ;-) ).

Comment: Yeah, my country code returns nl_BE, which is AZERTY. I guess there is no true answer to my question..

Comment: except the option you were considering, with my considerations: check the locale against the list of keyboards that have the <key>z</key> displaced from qwerty keyboards, and let the user change it in case the automatic checking does not work for him.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that InputContext#getLocale() returns null on Mac :(

Comment: then you're stuck with user defined preference :-s The other option would be for you to code a JNI interface for the layout engine of most of the popular OS and use it to check what keyboard the user is using. But that may be a lot of work and way beyond your project and a lot of trouble for your users :-)

Comment: Indeed, atm the product is in public beta. I'll just keep my fingers crossed that Oracle _finally_ releases a bugfix release with this bug fixed

Comment: It looks like they won't fix it for Java 8. Only in the next version. On German keyboards Z and Y are swapped. So the shortcuts for Undo and Redo are swapped.