# How to fix the non-qwerty keyboard layout bug in javafx for MAC OS

Tags: java, macos, javafx, key-bindings

I've been trying to fix a bug that only happens for MAC users of an app. The shortcut 'Ctrl+Z' or similar works in both azerty and qwerty for windows and linux, but it is somehow only working on Qwerty MAC, even though you change your keyboard layout.
I know the issue has been talked already : [how to detect if a users keyboard is in AZERTY in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014175/how-to-detect-if-a-users-keyboard-is-in-azerty-in-java)
and is a known bug : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087915
but I think I'm too dumb to fix it by myself, that's why I'm asking for help.

The current code is this way :

```
        final KeyCodeCombination keyCombREDO = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Y, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);
        final KeyCodeCombination keyCombSAVE = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);
        final KeyCodeCombination keyCombNEW = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.N, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);
        final KeyCodeCombination keyCombUNDO = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Z, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);
        InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();
        String loc = context.getLocale().toString();
        System.out.println(loc);  
        // javafx keyboard layout bug management 
        if (OS.current == OS.mac) {
            if (loc.equals("fr")) {
                Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);

            } else {
                Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
            }
        }
```

But the bug management condition don't seem to work.